# New method for Euler 13, code not working properly

Tags: java

Work out the first ten digits of the sum of the following one-hundred 50-digit numbers.

I have basically tried to add the last digit of the each number and then keep the last digit of the sum in an array while the remaining digits get added to the second last digit and so on..

For some reason I cannot get the correct output, I have been looking for 2 hours but cannot find the an error.

This is the code:

```
public class Thirteen
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String numbers[] = {"37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250 ",
             "46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538 ",
             "74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629 ",
             "91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250 ",
             "23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676 ",
             "89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757 ",
             "28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738 ",
             "44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318 ",
             "47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276 ",
             "70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951 ",
             "62176457141856560629502157223196586755079324193331 ",
             "64906352462741904929101432445813822663347944758178 ",
             "92575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407 ",
             "58203565325359399008402633568948830189458628227828 ",
             "80181199384826282014278194139940567587151170094390 ",
             "35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586 ",
             "86515506006295864861532075273371959191420517255829 ",
             "71693888707715466499115593487603532921714970056938 ",
             "54370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604 ",
             "53282654108756828443191190634694037855217779295145 ",
             "36123272525000296071075082563815656710885258350721 ",
             "45876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045 ",
             "17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412 ",
             "81142660418086830619328460811191061556940512689692 ",
             "51934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483 ",
             "62467221648435076201727918039944693004732956340691 ",
             "15732444386908125794514089057706229429197107928209 ",
             "55037687525678773091862540744969844508330393682126 ",
             "18336384825330154686196124348767681297534375946515 ",
             "80386287592878490201521685554828717201219257766954 ",
             "78182833757993103614740356856449095527097864797581 ",
             "16726320100436897842553539920931837441497806860984 ",
             "48403098129077791799088218795327364475675590848030 ",
             "87086987551392711854517078544161852424320693150332 ",
             "59959406895756536782107074926966537676326235447210 ",
             "69793950679652694742597709739166693763042633987085 ",
             "41052684708299085211399427365734116182760315001271 ",
             "65378607361501080857009149939512557028198746004375 ",
             "35829035317434717326932123578154982629742552737307 ",
             "94953759765105305946966067683156574377167401875275 ",
             "88902802571733229619176668713819931811048770190271 ",
             "25267680276078003013678680992525463401061632866526 ",
             "36270218540497705585629946580636237993140746255962 ",
             "24074486908231174977792365466257246923322810917141 ",
             "91430288197103288597806669760892938638285025333403 ",
             "34413065578016127815921815005561868836468420090470 ",
             "23053081172816430487623791969842487255036638784583 ",
             "11487696932154902810424020138335124462181441773470 ",
             "63783299490636259666498587618221225225512486764533 ",
             "67720186971698544312419572409913959008952310058822 ",
             "95548255300263520781532296796249481641953868218774 ",
             "76085327132285723110424803456124867697064507995236 ",
             "37774242535411291684276865538926205024910326572967 ",
             "23701913275725675285653248258265463092207058596522 ",
             "29798860272258331913126375147341994889534765745501 ",
             "18495701454879288984856827726077713721403798879715 ",
             "38298203783031473527721580348144513491373226651381 ",
             "34829543829199918180278916522431027392251122869539 ",
             "40957953066405232632538044100059654939159879593635 ",
             "29746152185502371307642255121183693803580388584903 ",
             "41698116222072977186158236678424689157993532961922 ",
             "62467957194401269043877107275048102390895523597457 ",
             "23189706772547915061505504953922979530901129967519 ",
             "86188088225875314529584099251203829009407770775672 ",
             "11306739708304724483816533873502340845647058077308 ",
             "82959174767140363198008187129011875491310547126581 ",
             "97623331044818386269515456334926366572897563400500 ",
             "42846280183517070527831839425882145521227251250327 ",
             "55121603546981200581762165212827652751691296897789 ",
             "32238195734329339946437501907836945765883352399886 ",
             "75506164965184775180738168837861091527357929701337 ",
             "62177842752192623401942399639168044983993173312731 ",
             "32924185707147349566916674687634660915035914677504 ",
             "99518671430235219628894890102423325116913619626622 ",
             "73267460800591547471830798392868535206946944540724 ",
             "76841822524674417161514036427982273348055556214818 ",
             "97142617910342598647204516893989422179826088076852 ",
             "87783646182799346313767754307809363333018982642090 ",
             "10848802521674670883215120185883543223812876952786 ",
             "71329612474782464538636993009049310363619763878039 ",
             "62184073572399794223406235393808339651327408011116 ",
             "66627891981488087797941876876144230030984490851411 ",
             "60661826293682836764744779239180335110989069790714 ",
             "85786944089552990653640447425576083659976645795096 ",
             "66024396409905389607120198219976047599490197230297 ",
             "64913982680032973156037120041377903785566085089252 ",
             "16730939319872750275468906903707539413042652315011 ",
             "94809377245048795150954100921645863754710598436791 ",
             "78639167021187492431995700641917969777599028300699 ",
             "15368713711936614952811305876380278410754449733078 ",
             "40789923115535562561142322423255033685442488917353 ",
             "44889911501440648020369068063960672322193204149535 ",
             "41503128880339536053299340368006977710650566631954 ",
             "81234880673210146739058568557934581403627822703280 ",
             "82616570773948327592232845941706525094512325230608 ",
             "22918802058777319719839450180888072429661980811197 ",
             "77158542502016545090413245809786882778948721859617 ",
             "72107838435069186155435662884062257473692284509516 ",
             "20849603980134001723930671666823555245252804609722 ",
             "53503534226472524250874054075591789781264330331690 " };

            String final_sum[]=new String[50];

            int sum=0;
            for(int x=49;x>=0;x--)
            {   

                for(int y=0;y<100;y++)
                {   
                    int temp=Integer.parseInt(numbers[y].substring(x,x+1));

                    if(y==0)
                    {
                        temp=temp+sum;
                        sum=0;
                    }
                    sum=sum+temp;
                }
                String s=String.valueOf(sum)+" ";

                int len=s.length();
                final_sum[x]=s.substring(len-2,len-1);
                sum=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0,len-2));
            }
            System.out.println("ANSWER");
            for(int x=0;x<50;x++)
            {
                System.out.print(final_sum[x]);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to work with such data.